# Understanding a proof behind euler totient function property

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing, totient-function

[image]

I do not understand what does $\mathbb{U_n}$ symbol mean, is it just any set that we used the $\mathbb{U}$ letter for? So if I understand correctly we want to show that $\mathbb{U_n}$ and $\mathbb{U_a\times U_b}$ is one to one. Why do we already have the correspondence between integers ? Can somebody explain how does the proof work.

Comment: Where did you get Theorem 3.8.7? If it was from a book, then the definition of $\phi(n)$ **and** $U_n$ must have been given earlier in the book. Did you look for that?

Comment: @Somos I got it from https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/higher_math_online/section03.08.html

Comment: Those notes have an entire chapter titled $\mathbb U_n$, [here](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/higher_math_online/section03.04.html)  Unsurprisingly, the definition is there.

Comment: I think $U_n$ denotes the set of units in the ring $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$. This proof is related to the abstract version of the *Chinese remainder theorem*.